# Troubleshooting on setup a multi node hyperledger fabric on multi hosts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the tutorial:

https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-up-a-multi-node-hyperledger-fabric-network-with-docker-swarm/

I have created 3 linux vms with hostnames: org0, org1,org2.

I have followed the first two steps and I have created an overlay network.But in the step 3 it says that we should add in the .env file the following rules:

Step 3 : Node configuration and moving crypto certs

Before node configuration, make sure you’ve the certs moved to the absolute path that is mentioned in the volumes. Clone the repo in all the machines and run the following command which will move the certs to the corresponding folder.

./move_crypto.sh
In order to configure the node’s hostname, you’ve to edit the .env file that is located in the root of network folder.

nano .env
Update the following variables to corresponding hostname of machines. You must reference the hostname of nodes from the above mentioned results.

ORG1_HOSTNAME="ORG1 HOSTNAME"

ORG2_HOSTNAME="ORG1 HOSTNAME"

ORG2_HOSTNAME="ORG1 HOSTNAME"

After editing, save it and close. Now you’ve to run our script to update this in all our compose files. In order to do that you can run the following command.

./populate_hostname.sh

Should I add org0 in these rules in the .env file and run the scripts in all hosts?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit that populate_hostname script like this:

```
ORG1_HOSTNAME=org0

ORG2_HOSTNAME=org1

ORG2_HOSTNAME=org2
```

After editing, save it and close and then run this script on all the three nodes.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I did that and didn't work, when I run the ./start_all.sh and after docker service ls | grep "0/1" should return nothing.But it returns 7 failed containers.